# How do I validate for a empty query string parameter in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to validate for a empty Id value in the url.

> ../Task/EditEmployee/afccb22a-7cfd-4be5-8f82-9bd353c13b16

I want that if the Id is empty

> ../Task/EditEmployee/

Than redirect the user to a certain page.

```
public ActionResult EditEmployee(Guid Id)

{

//Some code in here

}
```

Answer (score 2):

It may not be the best solution but you can take id parameter as string and try to parse it like this:

```
public ActionResult EditEmployee(string id)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(id))
    {
        // handle empty querystring
    }
    else
    {
        Guid guid;
        if (Guid.TryParse(id, out guid))
        {
            //Some code in here
        }
    }
}
```

**Or**

You can also create a regex constraint on the route but that may be too complicated and hard to understand. Map this route before the default one.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "TastEditEmployee",
    "Task/EditEmployee/{id}",
    new { controller = "Task", action = "EditEmployee" },
    new { id = @"^(\{{0,1}([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}\}{0,1})$" } 
);
```

Then you can use id parameter as Nullable Guid.

```
public ActionResult EditEmployee(Guid? id)
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion, I'm still very new in mvc and haven't done any mapping and therefor not familiar with it. I used your first suggestion and it worked perfectly, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Since `Guid` is a struct, the value of `Id` will be `Guid.Empty` if it was omitted. You can check for that.

```
public ActionResult EditEmployee(Guid Id)
{
   if (Id == Guid.Empty) throw new ArgumentException("Id not specified.");
}
```

Comment: This will also throw an exception when id is not empty and not a value in Guid format.

Comment: Yes, and I don't think that's undesirable either.

Comment: Thank you very much but this returned an error message...I want it to validate the query string before it even reaches the code part where it requires the Id. I don't know if I am explaining it well